# JOGL Large Texture Out Loading Out Of Memory

Tags: java, opengl, textures, out-of-memory, jogl

I'm am loading a seven megabyte texture in JOGL using `TextureIO`, but after about three seconds, the program crashes without displaying anything with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Yes, I understand that a seven megabyte image is a ridiculous size, but I still want to load it. By the way, is a 8192 x 4096 texture supposed to be seven megabytes?

I have already considered the idea of splitting the image into several smaller textures and loading them one at a time, but this won't cooperate well with the sphere class I already have written. I suppose I COULD do it if I absolutely HAD to, but I would love to avoid that particular course of action.

I am not running on any sort of embedded device (Android, iPhone, etc.), I have a good 2 gigabytes of RAM, not sure about the GPU's RAM, but I would be willing to be it's enough to hold a seven megabyte texture. I have a 32-bit installation of Java and a 32-bit Windows computer, if any of that information helps.

Any ideas on why I'm running out of memory and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** I might be on to something, and everybody experienced might be slapping their foreheads, but the error says: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

I'm guessing the 'Java heap space' part will help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to increase the size of the heap at startup and its maximum size with -Xms and -Xmx:
[Oracle Java manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Be aware that your graphics card might not support such a big texture anyway, look at [GL.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL.html#GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE).

You should rather ask your questions about JOGL on [its official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org).

Comment: For `GL.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`, it prints 3379. What is that number? Kilobytes? Dimensions? Pixels?

Comment: Also, how do I find the current heap size?

Comment: GL.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is an OpenGL constant that allows to get the maximum texture size in pixels (maximum width or height). Use my source code to get the maximum texture size: https://github.com/gouessej/Ardor3D/blob/master/ardor3d-jogl/src/main/java/com/ardor3d/renderer/jogl/JoglContextCapabilities.java#L126

Comment: Use a profiler to know the current heap size, for example jvisualvm (provided with the JDK).